# Uploading Image in registration form to Local Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want users to be able to upload an image when registering. I'm not quite getting it right and hope you can help. I'm using asp.net c# and using the local database in Visual Studio.

This is what I have so far, HTML:

```
<tr>
<td class="auto-style3">Image </td>
<td class="auto-style4">
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  />
```

Backend:

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection   (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
        SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE ([Username] = @user)", conn);
        check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextBoxUN.Text);
        int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

        if (UserExist > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("Username already exists");

        }
        else
        {

string insertQuery = "insert into Users   (FirstName,SecondName,UserName,Password,Email,ProductOwner,ScrumMaster,Developer,ConfirmPassword, Image) values(@FName,@SName,@UserName,@Password,@Email,@ProductOwner,@ScrumMaster,@Developer,@ConfirmPassword,@Image)";
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", TextBoxFN.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SName", TextBoxSN.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", TextBoxUN.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBoxPass.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConfirmPassword", TextBoxConPass.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductOwner", CheckBoxProduct.Checked.ToString());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScrumMaster", CheckBoxScrum.Checked.ToString());

com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Developer", CheckBoxDeveloper.Checked.ToString());
                com.Parameters.Add("@Image");
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: what problem \ errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to save the image on disk:

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    // you have to create a folder in which to store the images
    var savePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UserImages"), FileUpload1.FileName;
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
}
```

you need to save the file name in the database:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@Image", FileUpload1.FileName);
```

You have to make sure that the folder does not contain a file with the same name.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm getting somewhere although I'm getting this error when clicking submit:                                      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with image'

Comment: You get this error because you specified in SQL that the column is of "image" type, this means that you store the actual image in the database which is not recommended. A best practice is to store the image files on disk and in the database a reference to the file (like the filename). For this to work you need to alter the column Image and change the type from "image" to "nvarchar"